# Tweepy stream ignoring some twitter accounts

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am working on the finishing touches on my tweepy twitter bot for my LED. I have been testing it with different accounts, and something weird is going on. With my personal account I tweet and it does nothing. My filter doesn't detect the hashtags and it just ignores everything. My friends have been able to use it, so I decided to log onto a separate twitter account. I can tweet there and my bot sees it and recognizes it.

I really have no clue what could cause this. Is it a problem with my bot, or is it with the accounts?

```
import tweepy
import requests
import json

consumer_key = 'nein'
consumer_secret = 'das'
access_token = 'ist'
access_token_secret = 'böse'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

user = api.me()
print(user.name)

counter = 0


class LEDStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, raw_data):
        with open("tweets.json", "w") as write_file:
            write_file.write(raw_data)
        data = json.loads(raw_data)

        variable_checker(data)


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            print('Stream disconnect, because of rate limit error')
            return False
        else:
        print('Unknown Error ' + status_code)
        return False


def retweet_tweet(tweet_id):
    api.retweet(tweet_id)
    api.create_favorite(tweet_id)


def tag_checker(tag_list):
    for i in range(0, len(tag_list)):
        iterated_tag = tag_list[i]['text']
        if iterated_tag == 'HUNTER_LED_ON':
            return iterated_tag

        elif iterated_tag == 'HUNTER_LED_OFF':
            return iterated_tag

        elif iterated_tag == 'led_test':
            return iterated_tag

    return ' '


def variable_checker(json_file):
    if 'delete' in json_file:
        # If the tweet was deleted do nothing
        print('Delete')

    else:
        usr = json_file['user']['screen_name']

        tweet_id = json_file['id_str']
        print(tweet_id)

        text = json_file['text']

        tag_list = json_file['entities']['hashtags']

        tag = tag_checker(tag_list)

        data_check(usr, tweet_id, tag, text)


def data_check(twitter_user, tweet, tag, text):
    if tag == 'HUNTER_LED_OFF' and not text.startswith('RT'):
        requests.get('http://192.168.1.175/off')
        retweet_tweet(tweet)
        api.update_status('I turned the led off for you', tweet)
        print('off')
        return

    elif tag == 'HUNTER_LED_ON' and not text.startswith('RT'):
        requests.get('http://192.168.1.175/on')
        retweet_tweet(tweet)
        api.update_status('I turned the led on for you', tweet)
        print('on')
        return

    elif tag == 'led_test' and not text.startswith('RT'):
        retweet_tweet(tweet)
        reply = 'Nice test bro *highfives* keep up the good work'
        api.update_status('@%s %s' % (twitter_user, reply), in_reply_to_status_id=tweet)
        print('tested')
        return

    elif twitter_user == 'realDonaldTrump':
        api.create_favorite(tweet)
        requests.get('http://192.168.1.175/trump')
        print('Make America Great Again!')
        return

    else:
        return


ledStreamListener = LEDStreamListener()
ledStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=ledStreamListener)


ledStream.filter(track=['#HUNTER_LED_OFF', '#HUNTER_LED_ON', '#led_test'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with Twitter only making available about 1% of tweets for streaming to most users. Twitter does offer a "Firehose" account that gives you everything but it's rather expensive.

You could poll your users timeline every few seconds rather than using the streaming API.

```
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(user_id = user_id,count= 1)
```

Comment: So they just kinda randomly choose if you get to be seen thats kinda weird. Will it always ignore my one account or will it not.

Comment: I edited my answer. You might look into polling the users timeline every few seconds rather than using the stream listener.

Comment: So polling the timelines won't work, I plan on allowing anyone to mess with it.